# Dirac delta function of a function of different variable

Tags: limits, dirac-delta

We know that $\delta\big(f(x)\big) = \sum_{i}\frac{\delta(x-a_{i})}{\left|{\frac{df}{dx}(a_{i})}\right|}$. But how do we find $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{\delta(x-t_{i})} $$ if $t_{i}$ is an random entry of a Gaussian random variable?

Comment: It feels like it should be the distribution of $f$, since $\sum_{i=1}^{n} \delta(x - f(t_i))$ places out $n$ point masses at the randomly selected points $f(t_i)$, and we then divide it by the number of points.

Comment: I'm not sure if you're saying that the answer is $f$. Its not $f$. $$\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{\delta(x-f(t_{i}))}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}\delta(x-f(t_{i}))=1$$

Comment: @md2perpe Sorry, I forgot to mention you in the last comment and now I can't edit it.

Comment: No problem, SE flagged me anyway about a new comment.

Comment: I meant that the limit would be the random distribution of $f$. You see that the integral of it is $1$, as it should be for a probability distribution.

Comment: @md2perpe Oh right! It could be $f$.

Comment: I see that you have removed $f$ from inside $\delta$. Did you present the question incorrectly?

Comment: @md2perpe No. Initially I said $f(t_{i})$ is a random entry. I'm just calling $f(t_{i})$ as $t_{i}$ now. Its just notation.

Comment: @md2perpe Btw, you were right. It gives the same distribution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's solve the problem for the finite case and then apply the limits. Let $t_{i}$s be the random entries such that the value $T_{i}$ is assumed $n_{i}$ times.

Now, $$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{f(t_{i}))}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{j=1}^m{n_{j}f(T_{j}))}$$
$$=\sum_{j=1}^m{\frac{1}{n}{n_{j}}f(T_{j})}=\sum_{j=1}^m{p_{j}f(T_{j})}$$

Taking the continuum limit,
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n{f(t_{i})}=\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty}p(T)f(T)dT$$

Here, $p(t)=\frac{e^{-\frac{t^2}{2}}}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$ and $f(t)=\delta(x-t)$ giving the Gaussian distribution as the required answer.

-My professor's solution